# Exchange online- The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved

Tags: powershell-2.0, exchange-server

When i tried to connect to Exchange online by using powershell the following error arises for me.

$LiveCred = Get-Credential

Username

password

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange

-ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential

$LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection //While creating session the error

occurs."[ps.outlook.com] The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name

cannot be resolved"..

i have configured the winrm correctly..

C:\Windows\system32>winrm quickconfig
WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management  on this machine.

But still the error exists for me.

Comment: ps.outlook.com resolves to 132.245.6.135 for me.
Perhaps try `https://132.245.6.135/powershell/`

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same issue, however, I do notice the Uri value you are trying to use appears to have been updated to https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/.

The method given http://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/jj984289%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx did work for me, but at the moment it's not. Surely MS aren't down!!!